# How to write rspec test for a helper method inside a class in Ruby Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
module MyApp
  class V5::Org::LeaveRequests < Base

  helper do
    def leave_requests_for_member!
       error!(...) unless condition
    end
```

I try with my code:

```
    describe_api V5::Org::LeaveRequests do   
      describe '#leave_requests!' do
        context 'when LeaveRequestPolicy.access? is true' do

          it 'does not raise an error' do
            expect { leave_requests_for_member! }.not_to raise_error
          end
      end
    end
```

also I try:
`subject.send(:require_leave_request_feature!)`

but the error come up with:

```
got #<NoMethodError: undefined method `leave_requests_for_member!' for #<MyApp::V5::LeaveRequests:0x00007fd2985434c0>
```

And I also try:

```
allow(subject).to receive(:leave_requests_for_member!)
expect { subject.leave_requests_for_member! }.not_to raise_error


#<MyApp::V5::LeaveRequests:0x000072add28 @router=#<Grape::Router:0x00007fd2..>> does not implement: leave_requests_for_member!
```

Can you help me how to write rspec for helper method inside class?

Comment: A helper is really just a module (in this case an anonymous one) and if you're including it to provide private methods it's questionable if you should be testing it directly.

Comment: By "helper" do you mean ActionView helper methods? If so, those are just regular modules.

Comment: Why do you have this as an anonymous helper? If it's only for that class, probably try and just make it a normal instance or class method. If it's meant to be reusable (hence "helper") pull it into a separate file and you can test those methods on their own, like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598844/correct-way-to-add-helper-functions-for-an-rspec-spec

Comment: remove the wrapped `helper do... end` block and just leave the method `leave_requests_for_member!`. Fix the errors in rspec. there's no `describe_api` AFAIK. It should probably be `describe MyApp::V5::Org::LeaveRequests do...`